# Drawing Kinect Skeleton using Existing Data

Tags: c#, kinect

I have a .csv file that was collected in the past that contains all of the tracking information for the joints of a skeleton, including xyz coordinates. I was wondering if the Kinect SDK has built in functionality that will map these for you? So far, I've only been able to find information about mapping a skeleton in real time from the sensor. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to get each joint's XYZ coordinate and store them into an array that could be exported later or written directly into a file.

If that's what you need, the SDK lets you map each of the joint's coordinates. You could do the following:

Console.WriteLine will be used as example here, but you can write directly into a file with

```
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\test.txt");
file.WriteLine(lines);
```

You can iterate through each of the skeleton joints from time to time, get the coordinates and store them in a file of your choice or an array. So, you can map the coordinates with:

```
// Example using leftKnee joint
Joint j = skeleton.Joints[JointType.LeftKnee];

if (j.TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Left knee: " + j.Position.X + ", " + j.Position.Y + ", " + j.Position.Z); 
}
```